# Centos7 SystemD - Systemctl startup issue

Tags: centos, centos7, startup, systemd, systemctl

I have my bash script which I set my service to run ExecStart on - now my bash script with run directly via the user 'staytus' starts and stops things as expected but for some reason that I do not under stand yet when I run it via systemctl it throws errors!

Now since it works fine running as the same user I have the service set to use that kinda tells me the problem is with the startup file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Starts up procodile which runs staytus

[Service]
User=staytus
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startup/start.sh
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried adding a working directory, changing the user etc all with no luck - any other suggestions of what to try?

```
Oct 12 15:36:52 system-name start.sh: /usr/local/bin/procodile: line 10: require: command not found
Oct 12 15:36:52 system-name start.sh: /usr/local/bin/procodile: line 12: version: command not found
Oct 12 15:36:52 system-name start.sh: /usr/local/bin/procodile: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Oct 12 15:36:52 system-name start.sh: /usr/local/bin/procodile: line 16: `  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding'
Oct 12 15:36:52 system-name systemd: status.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
```

Comment: What errors does it throw?

Comment: added details to the org post

Comment: The /usr/local/bin/procodile is missing the ruby environment that has all its environment. Or is the start.sh script trying to source the procodile ruby script rather than execute it?

Answer (score 0):

On Systemd the environment variables for a process run by ExecStart is not the same as on the user terminal.

See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes

You'd have to check the environment variables where it runs ok (maybe using `set` command on the terminal) and add the needed ones on the systemd service definition using `Environment="VAR1=VALUE1" "VAR2=VALUE2"`. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment